# How to force the use of index in a specific relation on Oracle sql sentence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

First, these queries are executed on Oracle 11g

I am trying to force the Oracle to execute the index on the condition **manh_dist(tjoin1.fv,tjoin2.fv)<=8000** of the query bellow I am using hints to do it. However, it is not working.

This query:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(joinresult.tjoin1) */ count(*)
FROM
(SELECT tjoin1.fv, tjoin1.photoid
FROM minfv tjoin2, cophirfv500k tjoin1
WHERE
manh_dist(tjoin1.fv,tjoin2.fv)<=8000
) joinresult INNER JOIN cophirphoto500k lp
ON (joinresult.photoid = lp.photoid)
WHERE to_char(lp.dateposted, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= '2002/01/01' AND to_char(lp.dateposted, 'YYYY/MM/DD') <= '2006/11/01'
AND manh_dist(joinresult.fv, (SELECT cfv_sel.fv FROM cophirfv500k cfv_sel WHERE id=2))<=5500;
```

Has this execution plan:

[image]

In another attempt, the system stops using the index on the condition **manh_dist(joinresult.fv, (SELECT cfv_sel.fv FROM cophirfv500k cfv_sel WHERE id=2))<=5500**. But it does not use it on the other one, as it should be.

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(@subq tjoin1) */ count(*)
FROM
(SELECT /*+ qb_name(subq) */ tjoin1.fv, tjoin1.photoid
FROM minfv tjoin2, cophirfv500k tjoin1
WHERE
manh_dist(tjoin1.fv,tjoin2.fv)<=8000
) joinresult INNER JOIN cophirphoto500k lp
ON (joinresult.photoid = lp.photoid)
WHERE to_char(lp.dateposted, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= '2002/01/01' AND to_char(lp.dateposted, 'YYYY/MM/DD') <= '2006/11/01'
AND manh_dist(joinresult.fv, (SELECT cfv_sel.fv FROM cophirfv500k cfv_sel WHERE id=2))<=5500;
```

The new execution plan is:

[image]

Oracle does use index when I call this block separately.

```
SELECT tjoin1.fv, tjoin1.photoid
FROM minfv tjoin2, cophirfv500k tjoin1
WHERE
manh_dist(tjoin1.fv,tjoin2.fv)<=8000;
```

The execution plan it builds is:

[image]

*The system is not capable of gathering the right statistcs, that is the why I am trying to do it.*

How can I force the compiler to use the index on the condition **manh_dist(tjoin1.fv,tjoin2.fv)<=8000**, in the complex query ?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using a function based index. Here is a link: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_index_scan_fbi_sql.htm

Comment: It might help your query to clean up the predicates.  For example, changing `to_char(lp.dateposted, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= '2002/01/01'` to `trunc(lp.dateposted) >= date '2002-01-01'` will avoid type conversion and may help the optimizer make a better decision.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to use an index on a function that takes arguments from two different tables using "basic" Oracle.  You should look into geographic packages that provide such functionality.

Comment: It is possible to use index in this condition. If I execute the block separetaly the Oracle does so.

Comment: The problem is that for this case the Oracle does not have the right statistcs sometimes. Those functions I am using are a data cartridge.
That is the why I am trying to use hints. I don't think it will be possible by other means.

Comment: I have added some information into the question above in order to better answer the rised questions.